Real & Complex Analysis [Rudin, 3rd ed.] Theorem 6.13
There are a few other posts about this theorem already, but they focus on a different step of the proof. I restate the theorem and proof below.
Theorem 6.13: Suppose $\mu$ is a positive measure on $\mathfrak{M}$, $g \in L^1(\mu)$, and
$$\lambda(E) = \int_{E} g \; \text{d}\mu : \forall E \in \mathfrak{M}$$
then
$$|\lambda|(E) = \int_{E} |g| \; \text{d}\mu : \forall E \in \mathfrak{M}$$
Proof: By Theorem 6.12, there is a function $h$, of absolute value 1, such that $\text{d}\lambda = h \; \text{d}|\lambda|$. By hypothesis, $\text{d} \lambda = g \; \text{d}\mu$. Hence
$$h \; \text{d}|\lambda| = g \; \text{d}\mu$$
This gives $\text{d}|\lambda| = \overline{h}g \; \text{d}\mu$. Since $|\lambda| \geq 0$ and $\mu \geq 0$, it follows that $\overline{h}g \geq 0$ a.e. $[\mu]$, so that $\overline{h}g = |g|$ a.e. $[\mu]$. $\blacksquare$
My question has to do with the step
$$h \; \text{d}|\lambda| = g \; \text{d}\mu \implies \text{d}|\lambda| = \overline{h}g \; \text{d}\mu$$
At face value, it seems like an obvious implication (we just multiply LHS and RHS by $\overline{h}$). But the differential notation is only shorthand, so more precisely Rudin claims
$$\int_E h \; \text{d}|\lambda| = \int_E g \; \text{d}\mu : \forall E \in \mathfrak{M} \implies \int_E \text{d}|\lambda| = \int_E \overline{h}g \; \text{d}\mu : \forall E \in \mathfrak{M}$$
and I don't see the justification.

Roughly speaking, this should follow by writing $\bar{h}$ as a limit of simple functions.
